# Why does Laravel Query builder query return a different result set than the raw mysql query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

So i had this raw query:

```php
$rawquery = <<<SQL
    SELECT exercises.id AS id, r1.rating, ABS(CAST(r1.rating AS SIGNED) - :rating) AS diff
    FROM exercises
    INNER JOIN exercise_theme ON exercises.id = exercise_theme.exercise_id AND theme_id = 12
    INNER JOIN ratings r1 ON exercises.id = r1.exercise_id
    LEFT JOIN ratings r2 ON exercises.id = r2.exercise_id AND r1.id < r2.id
    LEFT JOIN results ON exercises.id = results.exercise_id AND results.user_id = :uid
    WHERE exercises.status = 'enabled' AND r2.id IS NULL AND results.id IS NULL
    ORDER BY diff;
SQL;

$results = DB::select($rawquery, ['rating' => 1500, 'uid' => Auth::user()->id]);
dd(count($results));
```

This query selects all exercises that don't have a result yet and since an exercise can have multiple ratings (history) i only want to select the most current rating (highest id).

When executing this query i get the expected result set containing 55 rows.

So now i converted this query to use the laravel Query builder:

```php
$query = DB::table('exercises')
    ->selectRaw('exercises.id as id, r1.rating, ABS(CAST(r1.rating as SIGNED) - ?) as diff', [$rating])
    ->join('exercise_theme', function ($join) {
        $join->on('exercises.id', '=', 'exercise_theme.exercise_id')
            ->where('theme_id', '=', 12);
    })
    ->join('ratings as r1', 'exercises.id', '=', 'r1.exercise_id')
    ->leftJoin('ratings as r2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('exercises.id', '=', 'r2.exercise_id')
            ->where('r1.id', '<', 'r2.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('results', function ($join) {
        $join->on('exercises.id', '=', 'results.exercise_id')
            ->where('results.user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->where('exercises.status', 'enabled')
    ->whereNull('r2.id')
    ->whereNull('results.id')
    ->orderBy('diff');
```

But executing this query returns a result set of 384 records (it seems that all ratings are selected, also old ratings).

I tried printing the raw query using $query->toSql() and running this query directly in my mysql console. The strange thing is, that this query returns the correct result set (count 55) but when i run the query in laravel, a different result set (count 384) is returned.

I checked my .env to verify that my database is set correctly and it was. So on the exact same database with the exact same query a difference is reported when running the query in laravel vs the console.

Comment: As an aside for anyone reading this comment later: `DB::getQueryLog()` does not work on its own. You need to first run `DB::enableQueryLog()` before you do your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```php
->leftJoin('ratings as r2', function ($join) {
    $join->on('exercises.id', '=', 'r2.exercise_id')
        ->where('r1.id', '<', 'r2.id');
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
```

`where()` doesn't compare two columns. It compares a column to a value. Meaning this `LEFT JOIN` will translate to

```sql
LEFT JOIN ratings r2 ON exercises.id = r2.exercise_id AND r1.id < "r2.id"
```

If r1.id is an integer value, then that condition will always be false.

---

Simply change the condition to

```php
->leftJoin('ratings as r2', function ($join) {
    $join->on('exercises.id', '=', 'r2.exercise_id')
        ->on('r1.id', '<', 'r2.id');
})
```